# Angular 4 - Generate select value from comma separated string

Tags: html, angular, drop-down-menu

I have a string with comma separated values. I would like to have this as the option value for my `select form` (drop-down box)

Example:

```
itemA, itemB, itemC
```

Into (consider this as a select form):

```
[Please select a value]:
itemA
itemB
itemC
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to slit your String and create an Array, after you can add NgFor to add your value in a select :

Assuming that you have got you data in `data`

```
let optionsplit =  this.data.split(',');
```

In view

```
<select name="yourinput">
   <option ng-repeat="o in optionsplit" value="{{o}}">{{o}}</option>
<select>
```

Or with ng-options

```
<select ng-options="o for o in optionsplit">

</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **`.split(',')`**

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedMetric">
     <option *ngFor="let metric of  toArray" [ngValue]="metric">{{metric}}</option>
</select>
```

AND in component.ts

```
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 4';
  DATA =  'itemA, itemB, itemC';
  toArray =  this.DATA.replace(/ /g, '').split(',')
}
```

**[`DEMO`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-select-example-t1artv?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: Given the string, this would rather be `let metric of  this.data.replace(/ /g, '').split(',')`. Otherwise, your values will have spaces.

Comment: Or maybe `[ngValue]="metric.trim()"`

Comment: I received an error: `Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: Parser Error: Unexpected token / at column 59 in [let books of currentModel.books.authors.replace(/ /g, '').split(',')]`
What does `/ /g` means?

Comment: @Sajeetharan what if the data is retrieved from restAPI? Would that make any difference on the way of splitting it?

Comment: even if you recieved from api, it will be the same